# Flash: AS3 – Bring symbol to front on rollover within movie

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseover, rollover

I have created a map of Europe in Flash using AS3. I am an absolute beginner. Each country has been converted into a movie (using lasso tool). These movies are on one layer (with slight outline visible) on main timeline. On the other main timeline layer is the original outline map of Europe.

I have managed to make it so when a country is rolled over, a box tweens in scale to full size (to later insert text in).

I need to make it so that when each country is rolled over, that country's text box (which appears on Roll_Over) comes 'to the front'.

At the moment a couple of countries' text boxes work perfectly (ie: filled with white and completely visible), but most are either buried beneath the main map, or threading randomly through the faint movie clip outlines (which are at the front).

I'm guessing that this has to do with the display list. The countries that work perfectly are probably at the top. But how do I make it so that the country rolled over immediately goes to the top and returns on Roll_Out?

This would complete my map so any help would be VERY MUCH appreciated.

I have used following code:

//FRAME ONE

```
this.stop();
movieClip_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, fl_MouseOverHandler_15);
function fl_MouseOverHandler_15(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndPlay(2); 
}
movieClip_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, fl_MouseOutHandler_67);
function fl_MouseOutHandler_67(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(1); 
}
```

//SECTION BELOW IS MY PROBLEM

```
movieclip_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,Rollover,false,0,true);
function Rollover(event:MouseEvent): void
{ 
setChildIndex(MovieClip(e.target),this.numChildren-1);
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the box part of the country movie clip or is added directly on the timeline?

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I spent some time and realised it didn't need code. I distributed all of the countries 'to all layers' (which then meant all countries were on the main timeline), I could then arrange the main map (bitmap) at the bottom, so that all the layers were on top of it. I then changed all of the country buttons as 0% alpha... and it worked. Once again, many thanks for the help and I'm sure the provided code will help in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling addChild() again to the DisplayObject/Movieclip to bring it to the front. Instead of:

```
setChildIndex(MovieClip(e.target),this.numChildren-1);
```

Try going:

```
addChild(MovieClip(e.target));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I spent some time and realised it didn't need code. I distributed all of the countries 'to all layers' (which then meant all countries were on the main timeline), I could then arrange the main map (bitmap) at the bottom, so that all the layers were on top of it. I then changed all of the country buttons as 0% alpha... and it worked. Once again, many thanks for the help and I'm sure the provided code will help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "layers" to bring objects in front of another.

constructor:

```
//Create the front layer
var frontLayer:Sprite = new Sprite();

//put all text boxes into front layer
frontLayer.addChild(textbox1); //etc...

//Add layer to mc
addChild(frontLayer);
```

rollover pops up:

```
textbox1.visible = true;
```

pop down:

```
textbox1.visible = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I spent some time and realised it didn't need code. I distributed all of the countries 'to all layers' (which then meant all countries were on the main timeline), I could then arrange the main map (bitmap) at the bottom, so that all the layers were on top of it. I then changed all of the country buttons as 0% alpha... and it worked. Once again, many thanks for the help and I'm sure the provided code will help in the future.